# Homeomorphism between quotient of $R^{n+1 }-{0 } $ and $ S^n \sim $

Tags: general-topology

I want to find an homeomorphism between the quotient space of $R^{n+1 }-{0 } $ and the quotient of $ S^n\sim $. The equivalence relation on  $R^{n+1 }-{0 } $ is defined by $x\sim y$ iff $y=tx $ for some nonzero real number $ x$. The quotient on $S^n $ is defined by the equivalence realtion $x \sim y $ iff $x=\pm y $ ,$x,y \ \in S^n $

I tink the following map may work, since it maps points in in the quotient of $R^{n+1 }-{0 } $ to the quotient of $S^n $, (more specifically it maps each line through the origin to one point of $S^n $ ?)
$$f(x)=\frac {x }{||x||} 
$$

Now first of all: is this map continuous? If I take a subset $U $ of $S^n\sim $ then $f^{-1 }(U) $ is a union of lines, hence open sets in the quotient topology of $R^{n+1 }-{0 } $, by the question above?

Secondly I need an continuous inverse than maps points of the unit sphere to lines in the quotient of $R^{n+1 }-{0 } $?

**An other edit**, it should be an homeomorphism between, the quotient of $R^{n+1 }-{0 } $ and the quotient on $S^n $ defined by the equivalence realtion $x \sim y $ iff $x=\pm y $ ,$x,y \ \in S^n $, not just $S^n $.

Comment: For your first question, one nice property of the quotient topology: if $f$ is a continuous map from $X$ into $Y$ and respects the equivalence $\sim$ on $X$ (i.e. $x\sim y\Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$), then $f$ induces a continous map from $X/\sim$ into $Y$. This comes quite easily from the definition.

In addition, you may want to start with a continuous map from $S^n$ into ${\mathbb R}^n\setminus 0$. Since $S^n$ is compact, $S^n/\sim$ is compact as well, so you only need to show that your    map is continuous and bijective to be sure it is an homeomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

These spaces are not homeomorphic: One is compact, the other is not. The correct claim is that $S^n$ is homeomorphic to the quotient of $R^{n+1}\setminus 0$ by the equivalence relation
$$
x\sim tx, t>0. 
$$

Edit: Now I see that you are considering a different equivalence relation
$$
x\sim tx, x\in R^{n+1}\setminus 0, t\in R^\times=R\setminus 0.
$$
Then the quotient is the real-projective space $RP^n$, it is not homeomorphic to $S^n$ unless $n=1$. Take a look at, say, Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" to see why these spaces are not homeomorphic ($RP^n$ is not simply-connected while $S^n$ is, for $n\ge 2$).

Edit 2. Now that the question is about two descriptions of $RP^n$, I will give an answer as a sequence of steps you can do in order to solve this problem yourself:

1. Show that $X=R^{n+1}\setminus 0$ is homeomorphic to $S^n\times R_+$. Hint: the first component of the map from $X$ to the product is
   $$
   f(x)=x/||x||.
   $$
   Wha should be the second component of this map?
2. Suppose that $X$ is a topological space homeomorphic to the product $Y\times Z$. Consider the projection $p$ of $X$ to the first factor. Show that the quotient topology induced on $Y$ via the map $p$ is the same as the original topology of $Y$. Now apply this to the case when $X$ is as in Part 1 and $Y=S^n$.
3. Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and you have subjective maps
   $$
   p: X\to Y, q: Y\to V, r=q\circ p.$$
   Consider the quotient topology on $Y$ induced by $p$ And then the quotient topology $t$ induced on $V$ by $q$. Consider also the quotient topology $t'$ on $V$ induced by the map $r$. Show that the topologies $t, t'$ are the same.
4. Now, apply step 3 to the maps
   $$
   p: X=R^{n+1}\setminus 0\to Y=S^n, q: Y\to V=S^n/\sim,
   $$
   where $x\sim y$ if and only if $y=\pm x$ and
   $$
   r: X\to V
   $$
   which is the quotient map for the equivalence relation
   $$
   x\sim t x, t\in R^\times,
   $$
   the group of nonzero real numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry, meant the qoutient of $R^{n+1 } - {0 } $ . Have now edited the question.

Comment: @Alexander: Please, edit your question again specifying the equivalence relation for your quotient. Then, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Have don that now.

Comment: @Alexander: With your equivalence relation the spaces are not homeomorphic. Your quotient is called n-dimensional real projective space.

Comment: Well if I define an equivalence realtion $x \sim y $ iff $x=\pm y $ on $S^n $, then they are homeomorphic?

Comment: I am not sure who "they" are here. Do you mean that $RP^n$ is homeomorphic to the quotient of $S^n$ by the antipodal map ($x$ is identified with $-x$)? Then the answer is yes. You really have to think through the question before asking it in order to avoid guessing on the part of your readers.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I'm sorry I have had to do all these corrections, this subject is jet new and hard to me. Thanks for your help!